# How would I get a Tumblr theme I'm making to automatically generate a tab for each post?

Tags: jquery, html, css, tumblr

Roseannebarr.tumblr.com

I have a theme I am working on and it is a theme with sliding tabs. Obviously I can put post tags in each div for the slider link BUT that will put ALL types of that post in that div. So if I put {block:Photo} in there then it would put all photo posts in that div. What I want it to do is post each post separately by generating a new link for each post.

P.s: image src is only because I am a new user.

Cant post the code, here it is.

http://roseanneconner.tumblr.com/post/2509329345

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you'll have to use the Tumblr API (with either JSON or XML) to grab the posts and redisplay them individually. To get an idea of when (and how) to use the API with JSON, you can check out one of my themes at elegantem.tumblr.com using the "sort posts" feature in the sidebar.

Comment: Um I honestly don't know. I don't think so, because that would be already what I have accomplished and put each post into the same div. I want all posts to be inseperate divs, so if the page has 2 photo posts, each photo post will have their own tab. If you look at the first link, you will see the general idea. There are only 4 tabs, but what I want is for the theme to display a new tab for each post. So each post has their own tab, and if the user has 15 posts enabled then 15 tabs leading to each separate post will appear.

Comment: Hmmm, if you're only keen on using the Tumblr templating system, and staying away from the API, then I would suggest using jquery to append a unique class/ID to each div. Something like <div class=”photo 1”>, where the digit increments with each loop. That way you you'll have unique divs AND be able to create the tabs...